# how to write answers in textArea GUI from base code

Tags: java, user-interface

I had some questions earlier regarding this base code which were
solved here but now my issue is that i have to take this code and get
out the result in GUI textArea. What ive done so far is that ive
designed a textArea and a button but now im stuck.  I dont know how to
translate that code i used as a base into the GUI and make it possible
to click on the button and display the answers into the textdisplay. I
dont know if i should copy this base code somewhere or do i need to do
totally different thing inside of the GUI? For instance under
jButtonActionPerformed, what  do i need to do... im sorry im new to
this and so lost. Ive googled all day but its hard to understand.

Here is the base code :

```
import java.lang.String;
class Vara {              


    //Deklarerar variabler 

    private String name; 
    private double price; 
    private int antal;

    //tildela konstruktorer för de deklarerade variablerna 
    public Vara (String name, int antal, double price) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.antal = antal;
        this.price = price; 
    } // slut constructor

    public void setName(String name)  {  
        this.name = name; } 

    public void  setPrice (double price) { 
        this.price = price; } 

    public void setAntal (int antal)  {  
        this.antal = antal;  }

    public String getName() {    
        return this.name;} 

    public double getPrice() {   
        return this.price; } 

    public int getAntal() {    
        return this.antal; }     
}

//testklassen ska stå som en egen klass
   class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Vara var = new Vara("Banan",5, 12.5);


 System.out.println("Namnet är " +var.getName() +" och priset är " +var.getPrice() +" och antalet är "+var.getAntal() );// här slutar system.out


}
}
```

And here is the beginning of my code in GUI which i havent done anything on so far except creating a textArea and a button.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(69, 69, 69))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 361, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 231, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      txtDisplay.setText(null);
       txtDisplay.append(String.valueOf(String)+"\n");  
       // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in GUI Class make set the modifier to "Public Static" so it can be accessed from other class.

```
public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
```

then you can enter Value in this jTextArea1 from other classes. by accessing directly like this

```
NewJFrame.jTextArea1.append("text to append");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not obvious if you want to put in data into your `JTextArea` or to read the content entered in the `JTextArea` in order to store it somewhere else. I will answer for both cases.

An elegant way to wire up data and GUI is to insert the data model object (in your case an instance of the class `Vara`) into a GUI object. E.g. this can be done right at the GUI object creation as shown in the code below. I commented each new line in your code with "// CHANGED: ...".

```
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

      // CHANGED: store the model for this GUI
      private Vara vara;

      /**
      * Creates new form NewJFrame
      */
      public NewJFrame(Vara vara) { // CHANGED: provide the model for this GUI
        this.vara = vara; // CHANGED: store the model for this GUI
        initComponents();

        // CHANGED: set TextArea content according to the data in the
        // provided model object (if this is what you want)
        jTextArea1.setText(vara.getName());
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        txtDisplay.setText(null);
        txtDisplay.append(String.valueOf(String)+"\n");  

        // CHANGED: read the entered text from the TextArea and store it as the
        // new name of the Vara object (if this is what you want to happen when
        // the user clicks on the button)
        vara.setName(jTextArea1.getText());
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

      // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
      // End of variables declaration
}
```

**Some tips for a better programmer life:**

- use English everywhere, also in the comments
- always name the GUI elements reasonable, e.g. your `jButton1` could be `btnSave` ("btn" stands for Button) and your `jTextArea1` could be `taVaraName` ("ta" stands for TextArea) - this greatly increase readability of your GUI code and makes debugging and maintaining much easier
- use Eclipse for Java development, esp. if you want to build GUIs. It comes with a plugin called [Eclipse WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). This is "a powerful and easy to use bi-directional Java GUI designer", means you can: (1) easily drag-and-drop your GUI elements and get the code automatically generated for you; (2) modify any part of the code and see the drag-and-drop view automatically changing accordingly. It generates much cleaner and often shorter GUI code than the one you posted and lets you modify everything (does not have the "don't modify" parts you have in your code)